# Local Windows Debugger dialog promt gone

Tags: visual-studio

I am using visual studio for my game project, when I make changes on my code I click "Local Windows Debugger" button.

And small dialog window opens: asks whether rebuild(not sure), or run latest working exe or cancel

But now when I click "Local Windows Debugger" this dialog never appears again and runs latest working exe.

I dont know maybe I clicked "dont show this warning again!" option (if there is such this option)

Can anyone  help me to find way to show this dialog again?